can't seem to find the solution for this back-end api gradle build error
when i try to build the gradle component it shows me different errors and one of them is:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
error screenshot
and i can't seem to find the solution
i tried to clean and rebuild but that didn't work and i tried to downgrade gradle from 8.8 to 8.6 but that also didn't work .. can't seem to know where the issue is comming from
